# Tar command in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, tar

I'm using the command in a script:

```
tar -czf -"$fsrc"/* > ./"$fdest"/"$fname"
```

In a script to take user defined source folder and redirect to a user defined destination with a user defined name.

When I use the command in the terminal by itself like:

```
tar -czf - Documents/* >./backup/test.tar.gz
```

It works fine but when run in my script I get:

```
archive.sh: line 172: .//: Is a directory
```

And nothing happens.

Comment: It looks like your script is not assigning values to `fdest` or `fname`

Comment: Immediately above the `tar` line you should consider a debugging statement such as `"echo fsrc='$fsrc', fdest='$fdest', fname='$fname'"` and then fix your code appropriately

Comment: Or use `set -x` so that you are shown exactly what your script is trying to do before it does it.  Or `set -u` to abort with error if trying to reference an unset variable.

Comment: You're right my script wasn't assigning values to my variables. Fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, my scripts wasn't assigning values to my variables. I have now fixed that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer for another 2 days.